# Script doesn't work with different number of digits in "if"

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jquery-ui to organize divs and save back on the server the changes.

To do so, I read some infos from the 2 divs directly involved, and send them through post in another page through ajax.

So, I have a code that reads, after a drag with update of the dom, the attr "pos" of the div moved and of the div after it.
If the attr "pos" of the first one is > of the second one, it triggers this script.

```
if (ui.item.attr('pos') > ui.item.next().attr('pos'))
        {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "muovi.php",
            data: { in:ui.item.attr('ids'), pos1:ui.item.attr('pos'), out:ui.item.next().attr('ids'), pos2:ui.item.next().attr('pos')},
            success: function(response){

                $.ajax({
                  url: "",
                  context: document.body,
                  success: function(s,x){      ( -> Reload the page )
                  $(this).html(s);
                  }
                });

                $(".overlay").css("visibility","hidden"); (-> to understand if something went wrong)
                }
        });
    }
```

The problem is, if I have divs like these ones:

```
[...]
<div class="game" pos="7" ids="something">
<div class="game" pos="8" ids="something else">
<div class="game" pos="9" ids="~">
<div class="game" pos="10" ids="~">
<div class="game" pos="11" ids="~">
[...]
```

If I move a div with pos 1-9 on a div with pos 1-9 i get no errors, same if divs in pos 10-99.
But if I try to move a 10-99 div back on a div 1-9, the script doesn't seem to work.

So, if there is a different number of digit, I have this problem. Is this resolvable without editing the "pos" field?
Is the problem clear? Should I add some more infos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the string into number before executing your comparison with [`parseInt`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp):

```
if (parseInt(ui.item.attr('pos')) > parseInt(ui.item.next().attr('pos')))
```

Comment: I found this out a moment ago. Thanks!